# Python pandas: Select columns where a specific row satisfies a condition

Tags: python, pandas, select

I have a dataframe dfall where there is a row labeled 'row1' with values 'foo' and 'bar'. I want to select only columns of dfall where 'row1' has the value 'foo'.

In other words:

```
dfall= pd.DataFrame([['bar','foo'],['bla','bli']], columns=['col1','col2'], index=['row1','row2'])
```

I want as result the column 'col2'containing: `['foo','bli']`

I tried:

```
dfall[dfall.loc['row1'].isin(['foo'])]
```

I get the error

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

Can anybody help me with the command? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your df against the scalar value, and then use `any` with `axis=0` and pass this boolean mask to `ix`:

```
In [324]:
df.ix[:,(df == 'foo').any(axis=0)]

Out[324]:
     col2
row1  foo
row2  bli
```

breaking the above down:

```
In [325]:
df == 'foo'

Out[325]:
       col1   col2
row1  False   True
row2  False  False

In [326]:
(df == 'foo').any(axis=0)

Out[326]:
col1    False
col2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This answer assumes that all columns contain strings. This is true for the sample data frame given in the question, but that is clearly a placeholder. If there are numeric columns, ``df == 'foo'`` will fail with a ``TypeError``.

Comment: @Schmuddi I can only answer what is stated, unless the OP fully describes the problem domain then this answer satisfies the current question

Comment: Great, thanks! To make it row specific I did: df.ix[:,(df.loc['row1'] == 'foo')]

Answer (score 0):

Using EdChum's answer, to make it row specific I did: 
df.ix[:,(df.loc['row1'] == 'foo')]